# Log Shipping potential backlogs

Tags: sql, logging

I plan to setup log shipping between our production server and disaster recovery site.  The network link between the two is not great.  The intention is to run log shipping every 15 minutes and typically this will mean less than 100Mb of transaction logs will be created which will be copied and restored to DR before then next 15 min interval.

Overnight jobs however can on occasions create huge transaction logs approaching 10Gb which will take over 4 hours to copy to DR.  Will subsequent log shipping jobs run and 'overtake' the previous job.

Answer (score 0):

no, the logs will be backed up on your main server and send to your DR server on a queue basis, so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had any issues with the sending of the log files.   Litespeed full backup (which does not have to use Litespeed ( .SLS files) )  but could use .bak file.  Their are scripts in which you should run and save have your primary prod server having a manual job for syncing and then have say the full backup daily and then a copy that is done every 15 minutes.  On the DR a few jobs that run every 15 minutes for copy and restore processes.

I have several Databases ranging from 200 GB to 900 GB and the network latency does not seem to be an issue for large .trn files to get copied over.  The bottleneck seems to be on the Restore process.

In general if you didn't inherit a disaster of databases with tables missing primary keys, then I would NOT recommend the old log shipping, there are much better ways  (Mirroring and Replication)